# how can you append a number to a double in swift

Tags: swift, numbers, integer, append, double

I am trying to make a calculator app in swift as a practise for my IOS development course. for that app I am trying to append a number to an existing double or integer after the user pressed on a specific button, but I don't know how.

if the user pressed on lets say a 5, then I want that the code should append that 5 to the numbers he pressed before

for instance:

the user has typed the following number:

```
6797.890
```

and now he wants to add the 5 to the existing number so that the number would be:

```
6797.8905
```

I really don't know how to do this in the code, and I really appreciate it if someone could help me by showing how or giving some resource website's for this problem

thanks a lot!

Benji

Comment: If this doesn't need to be performant, you could just convert the double to a String, add the 5 to the end, then parse it as a double. The only other way I know of is to use math, but that would require figuring out how many decimal places the number already has.

Comment: The user's input should be treated as a `String` (after all, you're likely using a `UITextField` for input). After the user enters a new digit, and you read the `text` property of the text field, and you now have the `6797.8905` as a `String`. Only then do you convert to a double (or whatever you're using) to store the number internally.

Comment: @paulvs I am using buttons, each number her own button

Comment: I see, what I suggest is that when the user presses a digit button, you can append that digit to a string that holds what the user has so far entered. Then convert that to a double.

Comment: @paulvs I also thought about that, but I didn't know how to do that either, so I thought to append a number to another number is easier than converting strings and append numbers to strings.

Comment: @userBSM Overwhelmingly, converting to and from strings to do operations is pretty much always easier. The main draw back is it's often (but not always) slower.

Comment: See this answer of mine about a way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50823038/8289095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you mentioned that you are supposed to use an `Int` or `Double`, but I would try and use `NSDecimalNumber` and `String` if you can. It will give you the precision you want and has a convenient way to turn the string into an `NSDecimalNumber`, `NSDecimalNumber(string: "6797.8905")`, as well as back to a string, `number.stringValue`. You can `enteredAmount != NSDecimalNumber.notANumber` just in case your user input is incompatible.

Comment: Is iT possible to append a nummer to the end of a NSDecimalNumner?

Comment: Ideally you would have your input be a `String` of text and then convert it to an `NSDecimalNumber` when needed. The problem is, if you think about it, there is no such thing as 'appending' a number to a numerical value. What you are doing is appending a digit, and the traditional numerical types do not really do that. Otherwise, I guess you could calculate the numeric value of what you are trying to add and then just add it normally, but that seems unnecessary and error prone.

Comment: In Swift, I’d use `Decimal` rather than `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You must process the input as a string.  If you process it as a double, the trailing zero will be lost and your code will not be able to distinguish between adding "5" to 6797.890 and adding "5" to 6797.89

Only convert from String to Double in one direction (from input to data) after displaying the initial value.